# How to serialize java object as xml attribute with jackson?

Tags: java, json, xml-serialization, jackson

is there a way to serialize a java var (e.g. int) via jackson as an xml attribute?
I can not find any spezific jackson or json annotation (@XmlAttribute
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute) to realize this.

e.g.

```
public class Point {

    private int x, y, z;

    public Point(final int x, final int y, final int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    ...
}
```

What I want:

```
<point x="100" y="100" z="100"/>
```

but all I got is:

```
<point>
    <x>100</x>
    <y>100</y>
    <z>100</z>
</point>
```

Is there a way to get attributes instead of elements?
Thanks for help!

Comment: There is no problem with the int type. What ever i tried, i just got xml elements instead of attributes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Okay I found a solution.

It wasn't necessary to register an AnnotaionIntrospector if you use jackson-dataformat-xml

```
File file = new File("PointTest.xml");
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.writeValue(file, new Point(100, 100, 100));
```

The missing TAG was

@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute=true)

so just change the getter to:

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute=true)
public int getX() {
    return x;
}
```

and it works fine. Just follow this how to:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml

> @JacksonXmlProperty allows specifying XML namespace and local name for
>   a property; as well as whether property is to be written as an XML
>   element or attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Have you registered [JaxbAnnotationIntrospector](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations)?

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();
// make deserializer use JAXB annotations (only)
mapper.getDeserializationConfig().setAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
// make serializer use JAXB annotations (only)
mapper.getSerializationConfig().setAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
```

Comment: So, in current versions of Jackson, you must set the annotation introspector on XMLMapper object, after using Builder to build it, like so:

`XMLMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(AnnotationIntrospector.pair(JacksonXmlAnnotationIntrospector(),JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(TypeFactory.defaultInstance() )`