# Converting a POJO to XML

Tags: java, android, xml, soap, pojo

I have to make a SOAP POST request as below

```
POST /sample/demo.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.website.org
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "https://www.website.org/Method"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Method xmlns="https://www.ourvmc.org/">
      <item1>string</item1>
      <item2>string</item2>
      <item3>string</item3>
      <item4>string</item4>
    </Method>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have acheived upto

```
POST /sample/demo.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.website.org
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "https://www.website.org/Method"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<Method xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"/>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and I have a POJO class with name Method and getter setter for all the item1, item2, item3, item4.
I need to convert that POJO to xml format which is

```
<item1>string</item1>
  <item2>string</item2>
  <item3>string</item3>
  <item4>string</item4>
```

and then POST it. can any one suggest how to do it ?
I have researched but didn't find any useful solution.

Comment: You can have a look at FasterXML's Jackson Dataformat XML. Here is the link: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml

Comment: I have seen FasterXML in lot of solutions but didn't find a single piece of code anywhere. could you guide me to a link where I can find POJO to XML coversion ?

Comment: Well here is one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712312/how-to-serialize-java-object-as-xml-attribute-with-jackson

Comment: @user2004685 I need to xml into a string rather than a  File

Comment: http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-convert-pojo-to-xml-in-android

Comment: @Logic You can use a `StringWriter` instead of File.

Answer (score 4):

Use below XMLUtil for converting pojo to xml

Usage Example :

1) Assume Pojo is Student

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Student")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Student {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String type;

    @XmlElement(name="Name")
    private String name;

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
 }
```

2) XMLUtil

```
import java.io.StringWriter;    
import java.util.logging.Logger;    
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;


public class XMLUtil {


    public static String toXML(Object data) {
        String xml = "";
        try {
            LOGGER.info("Generating xml for: " + data.getClass());
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(data.getClass());
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            //jaxbMarshaller.marshal(data, System.out);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(data, sw);
            xml = sw.toString();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            //handle your exception here
        }
        return xml;
    }

}
```

3) Set data to student object and pass to util

```
   Student st = new Student();
   st.setType("schoolStudent");
   st.setName("Devendra");

   String studentXml = XMLUtil.toXML(st);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using JAXB: https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.11/docs/ch01.html#documentation

For the actual posting, consider Apache CXF: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/index.html

For more information on generating XML from POJOs with JAXB+CXF: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxb.html