# How to serialize nested java object as xml attribute with jackson?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

This is a variation of [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712312/how-to-serialize-java-object-as-xml-attribute-with-jackson), however I have the case where I have json that looks like

```
{
    "point": {
        "meta": {
            "x": "100",
            "y": "200",
            "z": "300"
        },
    }
}
```

And would like XML that looks like

```
<point x="100" y="100" z="100"/>
```

However right now I have something that looks like

```
<point>
    <meta x="100" y="200" z="300"/>
</point>
```

I have a `PointMeta` class that is basically a wrapper around the attributes, is there a way to tell Jackson that I want it to treat this whole class as a collection of attributes in the top level `Point` class?

I'm also using Lombok to avoid boilerplate, the getters and setters are not the issue.

I've tried something like

```
@Data
class Point {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute=true)
    private PointMeta meta;
}

@Data
class PointMeta {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute=true)
    private String x;
    // And so on for y and z.
}
```

However, Jackson ignores the first annotation in the Point `class` with no warnings or errors. I want to tell Jackson that this field should be the XML attributes of this class.

Comment: IMHO jackson is working as expected. If you absolutely have to have the intended XML structure, is serializing PointMeta as XML instead of Point an option?

Comment: @AnujPatel Could you clarify what you mean? Do you mean using Jackson's `writeValue` method to write it as a Tree and then manipulating the structure after the fact?